# How to add extra width to table without disturbing the cells

Tags: html, css, background, html-table, box

I have a photo-grid table and I want to add a background colour to it that will extend across the entire page in a different colour to the background colour of the cells.

HTML:

```
    <tr><td><img src="http://i1377.photobucket.com/albums/ah56/ikeverington/Alpaca%20Rug_zpsgomcrq0x.jpg"></td><td><img src="http://i1377.photobucket.com/albums/ah56/ikeverington/cushion%205_zpsmdmzwdyp.png"></td><td><img src="http://i1377.photobucket.com/albums/ah56/ikeverington/Alpaca%20Throw_zpsbofn4msh.jpg"></td></tr>
    <tr><td id="desc">Rugs</td><td id="desc">Tapestries</td><td id="desc">Throws</td></tr>
    <tr><td><img src="http://i1377.photobucket.com/albums/ah56/ikeverington/Alpaca%20Cushion_zpscfdamg3p.jpg"></td><td><img src="http://i1377.photobucket.com/albums/ah56/ikeverington/Alpaca%20bear_zps4gpgvy79.jpg"></td></tr>
    <tr><td id="desc">Upholstery</td><td id="desc">Teddy Bears</td></tr>

    </table>
```

Styling:

```
table { 
    z-index: 4;
    padding: 10;
    background: #df0404;
}
#photo-grid img {
 width: 200;
 height: 200;
 padding: 20;
}
td {
 font-size: 30;
 text-align: center;
 font-family: arial;
}
#desc {
padding-bottom: 40; 
padding-top: 10;
}
```

I've considered using a span element, or just a div to create a coloured box that lays behind the table but couldn't get them to work. Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle please?

Comment: I've been using codecademy (I know it's not great), but you can see the code at work here: http://www.codecademy.com/izzyev/codebits/Rl1iT

Comment: So what exactly is the issue/problem you are facing? Do you want the background color of the entire page to be different than the table cells?

Comment: I want the table to be surrounded on the left and right by a different colour, but not above and below it...does it make sense?

Comment: I added a <section> tag before the table element and it worked fine. Check it out to see if this is what you are looking for. `<section style="background-color: pink;"><table id="photo-grid" align="center" >`